# How to embed latex code with LAtexDraw

Tags: latex

I am using latexdraw in order  to draw some scheme. I  would like to embed some latex code. When i click on the tex button my default Kile Tex editor opens, and it seems i can't embed the latex draw. I am expecting some pop-up window to  show in which i can write the tex code.

Under the Latex tab on Latexdraw preferences i put the TexLive bin dir: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux` and under the latex editor path i put my kile binary, because if i let it empty there is an error. When i put latexdraw as my latex editor, another latexdraw launches. I remembered from an earlier LatexDraw version that when i was clicking the TEX button a small box was popping up from Latexdraw such that i was able to write tex code and output it on my main drawing. How i can tell Latexdraw to  pop up this window in order to write Tex Code?